# fontFamily is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync But with Font.loadAsync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts

I'm learning react native by creating some projects.

I got stuck and unable to load custom fonts. I've followed [this](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/) guide from expo docs. but I'm getting an error

> fontFamily "raleway-bold" is not a system font and has not been loaded
> through Font.loadAsync.

Then I have use this `Font.loadAsync` in my code but I still get the same error.

Any suggestions?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    'raleway-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf'),
    'raleway-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf'),
  });

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return <Home />;
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={getFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a code of `AppLoading` component ?

Comment: I don't have any custom code of `AppLoading` component

Comment: Do I have add some custom code? sorry new to react native

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry. I don't realize it's an expo component. Try making your `getFonts` method async like this : `const getFonts = async () => { //your code }`.

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expo client and AppLoading bug [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10263)

You can try an alternative approach and not use AppLoading as below

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getFonts() {
      await fetchFonts();
      setFontLoaded(true);
    }
    getFonts();
  }, []);
 
  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. will try and update you.

Comment: Welcome @vajad57, please let me know and you may upvote the answer if it works.

Comment: I am not using apploading but my issue still persists. I am using expo sdk46